# Saving Assigned R object

Tags: r

I want to save an assign object.

```
stuff = c('a','b')
assign(stuff[1] ,1)

save(get(stuff[1])) #this doesn't work...
```

Are there any ways of referencing variable `a` without having to type `a` out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `?save` for details

```
save(list=stuff[1], file="a.RData")
```